# How to iterate through a list of services using CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to get the names of all the services in my machine that start with "ABC" and pass that name/string to another function. Unfortunately I have close to zero experience with CMD instructions. Aside from executing a few basic commands, I don't have any more experience.

I've tried getting the list of services that I need with this instruction

```
sc queryex type=service state=all | find /i "SERVICE_NAME: ABC"
```

And it returns all the N services that start with "ABC" ("ABC - 1", "ABC - 2", "ABC - 3", "ABC - N") which is what I need.

I then tried to save the results to a list, to iterate it later and that's when things stopped working

```
set list = sc queryex type=service state=all | find /i "SERVICE_NAME: ABC"

(for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
   echo %%a 
   //Call function(%%a)
))
```

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

In the meantime I'll keep looking for how to do this

Comment: Can you show us a real output ? (what is the char used to separate your different services ?) Also, iterate threw a list using batch is really hard, you should probably look for PowerShell commands (you can start a powershell command / script with this syntax : powershell -Command "Type your command here" or powershell -File "FilePath.ps1"). I can try do do something with powershell if you want

Comment: Batch is sensitive to spaces in an ordinary string `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG " to a value of " N". Remove the spaces from **both** sides of the `=`. Beyond that, you need to escape certain characters (especially redirectors) with a leading caret as shown in other responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to know that the for loop in batch does not work like other languages like java or python.

The easiest solution I fond for your problem is using PowerShell (I assume you can use it because your probably on a Windows computer if you ask questions about batch files).

First the command :

```
Get-Service ABC* | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

To show the list of the names of the services starting with "ABC*". (The select-object is useless you you want to do something else after)

Then you can call your function with a foreach loop :

```
Get-Service ABC* | ForEach-Object {do your stuff here}
```

To use your services name into the loop use "$_.Name" :

- $_ is to get the object
- .Name is to get the value of the property Name

Now you just need to call it from your batch file :

```
powershell -Command "Get-Service ABC* | ForEach-Object {do your stuff here}"
```

Good luck and feel free to ask other questions !

Answer (score 0):

To do it using the methodology you had attempted, *(`sc.exe` and `find.exe`)*, it would look a little more like this:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

For /F "Tokens=1,*" %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe query type^=service state^=all 2^>NUL
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "SERVICE_NAME: ABC"
 ') Do (Echo %%H)

Pause
```

If you prefer to use `powershell.exe` over `sc.exe` as offered in the answer by Thomas MONTIGNY, you could still do that within a batch file `for` loop too:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command
 "(Get-Service -Name 'ABC*').Name" 2^>NUL') Do (Echo %%G)

Pause
```